# Creating a partial index when field is not null

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to create a partial index on a field, but only when the field is not null. In other words, I want to be able to have many of the documents be able to store null, but for documents that actually have a value in the field, I want that value to be unique. Here is the code I tried to use

```
db.account.createIndex({ "email": 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "email": { $ne: null } }})
```

From what I thought I understood, this should index the `email` field when it is not equal to null.

But it gives the error:

```
"unsupported expression in partial index: $not email $eq null"
```

I tried to change `$ne: null` to `$exists: true`, but there are already multiple documents with null value for the email field, so it also threw an error. My schema has an email field for the document, so each document will automatically have an `email` field, meaning `$exists: true` won't work anyways.

Any help on being able to index a field only when it is not null would be great.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `$ne` is not supported expression operator,

> As per [MongoDB Partial Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) supported expressions are:
> equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the `$eq` operator), `$exists: true` expression, `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, `$lte` expressions, `$type` expressions, `$and` operator at the top-level only,

You can use `$type` to check is `string` like this `{ "email": { $type: "string" } }`, because null type is "null".

> **NOTE:**
>
> As noted in the [query coverage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#query-coverage) documentation for partial indexes:
>
> ---
>
> > *Since MongoDB will not use the partial index for a query or sort operation if using the index results in an incomplete result set.*
> >
> > *To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression (or a modified filter expression that specifies a subset of the filter expression) as part of its query condition.*
>
> **EX.** to use partial index for `$type` filter you have to use below filter:
>
> ```
> { "email": { "$eq": "foo@mail.com", "$type": "string" } }
> // or
> { $and: [{ "email": "foo@mail.com" }, { "email": { $type: "string" } }] }
> ```
>
> [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/diUZZGCPIQs)

Comment: Be aware that if with your `{ "email": { $type: "string" } }` partial filter expression, MongoDB wouldn't be able to use that if your query looks like `{ email: "foo" }`. This is because that would also match a document with email as an array containing "foo". To work around this you ned to query like so: `{ email: { $eq: "foo", $type: "string" } }`

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck yes you are right, there is a limitation/restriction in `$type` filter in partial index, i have updated more details.

Answer (score 2):

Based on inputs from @turivishal, updating here with actual code in the mongo shell.

```
> db.version()
4.2.6
> db.test2.createIndex({email:1},{unique:true, partialFilterExpression:{email:{$type:"string"}}});
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.test2.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.test2"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "email" : 1
                },
                "name" : "email_1",
                "ns" : "test.test2",
                "partialFilterExpression" : {
                        "email" : {
                                "$type" : "string"
                        }
                }
        }
]
//note, collection data exists with type "null"/empty values for email for 
//multiple names eg. srini, srini2,srini3 below
> db.test2.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e1c7087ded5e7627c7a19"), "name" : "john", "email" : "john@email.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e1c7087ded5e7627c7a1a"), "name" : "mary", "email" : "mary@email.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e1c7087ded5e7627c7a1c"), "name" : "srini" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e1c7087ded5e7627c7a1d"), "name" : "kate", "email" : "kate@email.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e2a2dfbbd49e82b415126"), "name" : "srini2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e2a39fbbd49e82b415127"), "name" : "srini3" }
//write error for duplicate value of email
> db.test2.insertOne({name: "mary1",email:"mary@email.com"});
2020-09-26T00:01:44.941+0530 E  QUERY    [js] WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test2 index: email_1 dup key: { email: \"mary@email.com\" }",
        "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e3790fbbd49e82b415128"),
                "name" : "mary1",
                "email" : "mary@email.com"
        }
}) :
```