# MongoDB unique partial index for an array of sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of documents of the following form:

```json
{
    "_id" : UUID("e8d8f0a0-d8e4-4234-b017-251e90ad5202"),
    "legalEntities" : [
        {
            "id" : UUID("5aa70699-e6c3-4aac-a860-0c0d44ea4ab3"),
            "dunsNumber" : "123456789"
        },
        {
            "id" : UUID("e8d8f0a0-d8e4-4234-b017-251e90ad5202"),
            "dunsNumber" : null
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Company X"
}
```

and I want the `legalEntities.dunsNumber` to be unique across all documents **except for null values**.

How can I achieve that in MongoDB?

(Tried with partial index on `legalEntities.dunsNumber`, but this approach doesn't seem to work).

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066830/creating-a-partial-index-when-field-is-not-null/64067615#64067615) and accepted answer, you can use a similar approach with partial index with providing partial filter `$type: "string"`.

Comment: @turivishal I do exactly the same thing, but it doesn't work for the array of sub-documents unfortunately. My current index definition is: `{ "v" : 2, "unique" : true, "key" : { "legalEntities.dunsNumber" : 1 }, "name" : "legalEntities.dunsNumber", "ns" : "profiles-test.legalEntities", "partialFilterExpression" : { "legalEntities.dunsNumber" : { "$type" : [ "string" ] } } }`

Comment: index looks good, make sure you have read provided Note in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64067615/8987128), To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression, ex `{ "legalEntities.dunsNumber": { $eq: "123456789", $type: "string" } }`

Comment: can you explain what is not working? 1) it is allowing to insert a duplicate value or not throwing duplicate value error? 2) index is not using when find/aggregate/update queries? 3) anything else?

Comment: @turivishal When I insert another document with `legalEntities.dunsNumber` = null, the operation fails due to unique index violation, while I want the null values to be outside of the unique index.

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations in the partial index filter as described in [SERVER-17853](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17853), and A [discussion](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unique-index-with-partial-filter-type-string-index-in-array-of-object-throws-duplicate-key-error/112106) for the same scenario ​in MongoDB developer Forum.

For your use case, it requires `$elemMatch` and `$ne` operators but that is not supported yet.

My suggestion is to not use an array or index for now until SERVER-17853 is resolved.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I have no other choice than to use a sparse index and not store null values at all. This is possible in my case, but requires additional effort, as I'm mapping objects from strongly-typed DTOs.

Comment: yes you are right, I just workaround, the only option is a sparse index, if you don't include null property in document.